# URL redirect from one server to another

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm very new to `apache` configuration and seems to be lost in the wealth of information posted on the web. I have a problem in hand and though it seems easy, but I'm unable to find the solution. I request you to kindly help me out.

The scenario is that I have a URL such as `https://myurl.com/internaltool` that points to `server A`, and I have a `server B`, which is the exact replica of `server A`. `Server B` works as a back up server, and during failure of `server A`, I would like my `URL` to point to `server B`.Can someone please help me out with this. 
I searched and found that `Redirect` is the command to be used, but I failed to understand if the server is down, then possibly I won't be able to `ssh`, then how could I point the URL to another server.

Looking forward for your inputs.

Comment: What kind of failure is it web server failure or server failure??

Answer (score 0):

You could either do a `temporary` or a `permanent` `Redirect` with Apache (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) to your failover machine:

Server A -> Server B

As you pointed out, this is kinda useless: Not only that you can't login on `Server A` anymore when it crashes, `Server A` would not be able to send the `Redirect` to `Server B` at all (In most cases).

There are numerous ways to achieve such a failover. E.g.:

- DNS Failover - Not trivial, especially when the switch has to work automatically and fast.
- Using a HTTP reverse proxy on `Server C`. Keywords: `nginx` `proxy` `failover`. When `Server C` dies, nothing will work of course - welcome to failover hell.

In most cases its easier to make your application/setup more robust. Automatically restart a failing service, etc...